# Swift 3 UIButton multiple events not detected within a less than 16 millisecond window

Tags: swift, uibutton, event-handling, performance-testing

This is my first question on StackOverflow. I am trying to measure reaction time to stimuli and need multiple players and UIButtons for the players. The problem is if the two players in the code example are within 16 millisecond or less of each other both `UIButton` events come together and therefore the same time. I just did this in Android and had no problem.

I did try override of the `touches_began()` and the same problem. It seems as if the two UIButtons are being handled in the same interrupt as if they were a multi-touch which I have turned off for the two buttons.

I know the example is dumb but it does illustrate the 16 millisecond
 issue. Just tap a bunch of times and see how many ties occur. I looked at the results of testing and I got an approximate 16 millisecond issue.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var timer: Timer?
    var startTime: Double = 0
    var time: Double = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var timeValueLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timeValueLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func stop1Button() {
        let timeString = String(format: "%.3f", time)
        timeValueLabel1.text = timeString
    }

    @IBAction func stopButton() {
        let timeString = String(format: "%.3f", time)
        timeValueLabel.text = timeString
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        startTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.001,
                                     target: self,
                                     selector: #selector(advanceTimer(timer:)),
                                     userInfo: nil,
                                     repeats: true)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }


    func advanceTimer(timer: Timer) {
        time = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - startTime
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```